# Swift - TableView datasource from URLSession task

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous

I have to populate a `TableView` with some data fetched with an `URLSession task`. The source is an XML file, so i parse it into the task. The result of parsing, is an array that i pass to another function that populate another array used by `TableView Delegates`.

My problem is that `TableView Delegates` are called before task ends, so tha table is empty when i start the app, unless a data reloading (so i know that parsing and task work fine).

Here is `viewDidLoad` function. `listOfApps` is my `TableView`

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {

            super.viewDidLoad() 

            fetchData()
            checkInstalledApps(apps: <ARRAY POPULATED>)  

            listOfApps.delegate = self
            listOfApps.dataSource = self

        }
    }
```

`fetchData` is the function where i fetch the XML file and parse it

```
    func fetchData() {
        let myUrl = URL(string: "<POST REQUEST>");
        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "firstName=James&lastName=Bond";
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            self.parser = XMLParser(data: data!)
            self.parser.delegate = self

        }
        task.resume()

    }
```

while `checkInstalledApps` is the function where i compose the array used by `TableView Delegates`.

```
    func checkInstalledApps(apps: NSMutableArray){
    ....
    installedApps.add(...)
    installedApps.add(...)
    ....
    }
```

So, for example, to set the number of rows i count `installedApps` elements

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if (installedApps.count == 0) {
        noApp = true
        return 1
    }
    return installedApps.count
}
```

that are 0. Obviously, if i reload data, it's all ok.

My problem is the async call: first of that i used an XML  accessible via GET request, so i can use `XMLParser(contentsOf: myUrl)` and the time is not a problem. Maybe if the XML will grow up, also in this way  i will have some trouble, but now i've to use a POST request

I've tried with `DispatchGroup`, with a

- `group.enter()` before `super.viewDidLoad`
- `group.leave()` after `task.resume()`
- `group.wait()` after `checkInstalledApps()`

where group is `let group = DispatchGroup()`, but nothing.

So, how can i tell to the tableview delegate to wait the task response and the next function?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would forget about `DispatchGroup`, and change a way of thinking here (you don't want to freeze the UI until the response is here).

I believe you can leave the `fetchData` implementation as it is.

In `XMLParserDelegate.parserDidEndDocument(_:)` you will be notified that the XML has been parsed. In that method call `checkInstalledApps` to populate the model data. After that simply call `listOfApps.reloadData()` to tell the tableView to reload with the new data.

You want to call both `checkInstalledApps` and `listOfApps.reloadData()` on the main thread (using `DispatchQueue.main.async {}`).

Also keep `listOfApps.delegate = self` and `listOfApps.dataSource = self` in `viewDidLoad` as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

The cleaner way is to use an empty state view /  activityIndicator / loader / progress hud (whatever you want), informing the user that the app is fetching/loading datas,

After the fetch is done, just reload your tableview and remove the empty state view / loader

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by the fact that you currently have no way in knowing when the `URLSession` task ended. The `reloadData()` call occurs almost instantly after submitting the request, thus you see the empty table, and a later table reload is needed, though the new reload should be no sooner that the task ending.

Here's a simplified diagram of what happens:
[image]

Completion blocks provide here an easy-to-implement solution. Below you can find a very simplistic (and likely incomplete as I don't have all the details regarding the actual xml parsing) solution:

```
func fetchData(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
     let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
            self.parser = XMLParser(data: data!)
            self.parser.delegate = self
            completion()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    fetchData() { [weak self] in self?.tableView.reloadData() }
}
```

Basically the completion block will complete the xml data return chain.